# css class gets permanently added to button

Tags: javascript, css, addeventlistener

I have this piece of code for drumkit project for playing audio and add an transition effect to the pressed button. Try here [drumkitProject](https://heysujal.github.io/drumkit2/)

CSS

```
.key {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: 10%;
  margin:1rem; 
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}
```

Javascript

```
function playSound(e) {
        const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);

        const pressedKey = document.querySelector(
          `.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`
        );

        if (!audio) return;

        pressedKey.classList.add("playing");

        audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();
      }

      function stopSound(e) {
        if (e.propertyName !== "transform") return;
        this.classList.remove("playing");
      }
      window.addEventListener("keydown", playSound);

      const keys = document.querySelectorAll(".key");
      for (let index = 0; index < keys.length; index++) {
        keys[index].addEventListener("transitionend", stopSound);
      }
```

When I keep the button pressed the transition effect gets permanently added to the button and the button does not return back to normal. Why is that happening when I have removed the class as soon as the transition gets over.
Code:https://github.com/heysujal/drumkit2

Comment: Look into [Debouncing JavaScript events](https://gomakethings.com/debouncing-your-javascript-events/)

Comment: @Sujal I found out that this happens when user interacts with the `body` while transition is playing.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the effect is permanently added when the `transitionend` event is blocked from firing (like I said in the comments).
To fix this issue, you can just add a `setTimeout` in `playSound()` function, to remove the class, after certain duration.

```
function playSound(e) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);

  const pressedKey = document.querySelector(
    `.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`
  );

  if (!audio) return;

  pressedKey.classList.add("playing");

  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();
  setTimeout(() => pressedKey.classList.remove("playing"), 150);
}
```

Try it out on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TechySharnav/gy48wt6q/3/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the way how transitions are being handled for expensive properties like `transition` or `box-shadow`. I managed to reproduce this behavior in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but looks like Chrome always does it, while Firefox and Safari are more random.

An easy fix for you would be to replace `transform` in `if (e.propertyName !== "transform") return;` with a cheaper property, like `border-top-color`:

```js
if (e.propertyName !== "border-top-color") return;
```

But I'm doubtful if you want to rely on the `keydown` repeat in your app, since you have no control over repeat interval. You can consider disabling the repeating sounds entirely:

```js
function playSound(e) {
  if (e.repeat) return;
  // ...
}
```

Or, if you'd like to keep the repeating, I'd suggest implementing a custom timer for that, giving you the control over how long you want to wait before the next hit.